# Guardar datos de una ejecución a otra

Tags: java

Tengo unos métodos para escribir datos en un fichero, pero algo no funciona dado que no se llega a crear dicho fichero. He probado a poner distintas rutas pero no parece funcionar con ninguna. Estos son los métodos que tengo:

```
static final String ruta="app\\src\\main\\java\\com\\xxxx\\Data\\fichero.dat";

    ObjectOutputStream oos;
    ObjectInputStream ois;
    //Para que cuando el fichero existe no escriba el Formato de cabecera
    AppendableObjectOutputStream aos;
public void ComenzarEscritura()  
    {
        File fic =new File (ruta);
        if(fic.exists())
        {
            try
            {

                aos= new AppendableObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fic,true));
            } 
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else
        {

            try 
            {
                oos= new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fic));
            } 
            catch (FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

@Override
    public void Escribir(Serializable o) 
    {
        try
        {
            if(oos!=null)
            {
                oos.writeObject(o);
            }
            else
            {
                if(aos!=null)
                {
                    aos.writeObject(o);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void TerminarEscritura() 
    {
        try
        {
            if(oos!=null)
            {
                oos.close();
            }
            else 
            {
                if(aos!=null) aos.close();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Llamada a los métodos (he probado pasándole directament la url y no servía, por lo que hice el cast):

```
             public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            //Escribimos la nueva url en el fichero
            Serializable s=(Serializable)url;
            objDatos.ComenzarEscritura();
            objDatos.Escribir(s);
            objDatos.TerminarEscritura();
            //
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }
```

Comment: ¿Te da alguna excepcion? ¿Las rutas exiten?

Comment: No da ninguna excepción, simplemente no lo crea. En cuanto a las rutas, una de las que he probado es poner simplemente "Desktop\\fichero.dat" y ni con esa ha funcionado.

Comment: Prueba a hacer un .flush() a los output antes de cerrarlos.

Comment: Acabo de probarlo, pero el resultado ha sido el mismo.

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir el codigo que llama a estos metodos?

Comment: probaste con una ruta valida? del estilo c:\ ?.. mirandolo mejor, estas hablando de url? desde donde estas intentando escribir?